# t:datatable apply css on row

Tags: java, jsf, tomahawk

I am using `t:datatable` in my JSF application.

Can I change CSS of perticular **row** on bases of condition? Condition means with datatable variable render. Is it possible?
I am using jsf 1.2 (Although everyone but me has upgraded to jsf 2.0 :/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using `rowStyleClass` or `rowStyle`

> rowStyleClass="css styleclass"
>
> rowStyle="inline css style"

like this

```
<t:datatable id="myID" var="data" value="#{myBean.data}" rowStyleClass="#{data.someproperty eq 'someStringValue' ? 'someClass' : 'otherClass'}">
```